# How can I store previous wizard pages?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Actually i am trying to do a Wizard control. In which i have load 3 pages dynamically when click the next button. When i click the next button i need to store the page details so i have created a dictionary to store the usercontrol. Is there any other suggestions to store the previous page details.

Comment: I have found that, The UserControl which i used in dictionary is Windows.Forms.UserControl. but i have added the Windows.Controls.UserControl..

Comment: No No.. if anyone gave me some suggestions to store the previous page details, that would be helpful to me to learn WPF, I'm very new to WPF and MVVM.

Comment: Have a look at this great article: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF

Comment: @SvenG Why do not post this as an answer?

Comment: @PVitt I regarded this as not "worthy" for an answer as no real effort was involved retrieving this information ... besides from that I am not sure if "link-only answers" are frowned upon

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve your requirements. This is what I would do, which I think is very inline with the MVVM design pattern.

1. Define a ViewModel class that contains **all** the variables that you want to collect (regardless of the partition to pages.
2. Add a public property named 'currentPage'.
3. Define the frame of the wizard. Probably a <Window> element, with a StackPanel. The Window would have a title at the top, and an area at the bottom for the 'prev' and 'next' buttons (and 'finish' if you want to).
4. In the main area of the StackPanel put a  and bind its DataContext to the ViewModel
5. In the ViewModel create a Next and Pref commands (use Prism DelegateCommand, or implement your own lightweight version that derives from ICommand.
   6/ Also, bind the 'Finish' button to a command, with the appropriate CanExecute logic (have you collected enough data?).
6. The Next and Prev 'CanExectue' logic would look at currentPage. e.g. the Prev command CanExecute will return false when currentPage is 0.
7. You'll have 3 different data templates, one for each page. Each data templates will present different subset of properties you want to collect at that page. Bind the UI controls to properties at the ViewModel, and have the binding mode two way.
8. Derive your ViewModel from INotifyPropertyChanged, and have all the setters to fire the appropriate notification. It is required for at least the currentPage property, but for the completion of the solution do it for all properties.
9. In the Next and Prev command Execute method will modify the currentPage property (the Setter should fire notification). The view will update automatically.
10. For the main area ItemControl, implement a WizardTemplateSelector derived from DataTemplateSelector. Define it as a resource, and assign the ItemControl.ContentTemplateSelector using {StaticResource} binding.
11. If you want to, you can also have a List control at the left side of the Window, with the Selected Item Index bound to the current page.

EDIT (Explainer): The basic idea is to have a single ViewModel, which can be Viewed in several different Data Template, depends on the current page.